# Are Google API token.json files single use?

Tags: google-sheets, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I'm making a simple app to access google sheets that I have saved on google drive. I set up a project on google, created the Oauth credentials and ran the Python quickstart code to generate the token.json file.

Yesterday, after doing that, I ran this portion of the quickstart code and it ran perfectly and returned the rows from the sample spreadsheet:

```
###Add step to pull in previous staff comments, joino in MRN
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

###This only runs when not connected to NetExtender. Should work when ported to citrix but running locally for testing is going to be difficult

###Gsheets
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'


creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])

if not values:
    print('No data found.')
else:
    print('Name, Major:')
    for row in values:
        # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))
```

However, today when I run that code, it doesn't work anymore. I get an error:

('invalid_scope: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_scope', 'error_description':'Bad Request'})

Are the token files single use and would I need to generate a new one every time I want to run this (that's the only reason I can imagine it would work fine yesterday but not today)? If that is the issue, is there a way to program this so that I don't need to re-authenticate in Google and create a new token file every time I want to run this?

Thanks!

Comment: token.json is single user it shouldnt be single use.  can you try and delete or move the token.json and see if it works then?  You really dont need sheets and drive scope.  the drive scope will give you access to everything on a users drive account the sheets scope gives you access to all their sheets,   stick with the one you really need

Comment: @DalmTo I opened up the token file and it looks like there's an "Expiry" section with a date and time of yesterday at 9PM so it seems like it does expire. I have to assume that was the issue. Do you know of a way to do this without that issue?

Comment: @DalmTo Also - I'd like to ask about the scope stuff you mentioned. I reran the quickstart code and now it's working. However, it only works when I sue the https:www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly" scope but I don't want it to be readonly, I'd like to be able to write but when I use the spreadsheets scope without ".readonly", it says invalid scope. Any idea why?

Comment: you cant add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets and just that? make sure you delete the token file so that it forces you to reauthorize the code